# Replace with loc raises invalid type comparison

Tags: pandas

Replace with loc raises type error invalid type comparison. In excel both column are text. What is the mistake here?

```
d= {'col1': ['Very High', 'High'], 'col2': ['High', 'Very High]}
LL = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

LL.loc[LL['col1'] == 'Very High', 'col1'] = 4  #Error
LL.loc[LL['col2'] == 'Very High', 'col2'] = 4   #No error

col1                                  object
col2                                  object


C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py:1164: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  result = method(y)

TypeError: invalid type comparison
```

Comment: Can you provide an example dataset so we can actually see the things that cause the error?

Comment: it reads it from excel it is two columns in text form. See above. Thanks.

Comment: This does not generate an error for me.  What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: How can the dtype of col1 be `int64`, if the values are strings?